# PHP socket script loop not working

Tags: php, sockets, telnet

I have successfully created a PHP sever socket script. It accepts a string and reverses it.

I want the script to run continuously to accept as many strings. All the online help and tutorial says I should include socket_accept in a loop.I did so and now the script doesn't terminate after first input string but still wont accept any further input.

My Code:

```
    #!/opt/lampp/bin/php
    <?php


    $host = "localhost";
    $port = 3027;
    $con = 1;

    set_time_limit(0);

    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP) or die('Could not create socketn');

    $result = socket_bind($socket, $host, $port) or die('Could not bind to socketn');

    $result = socket_listen($socket, 3) or die('Could not set up socket listenern');

    while (true)
    {
        $spawn = socket_accept($socket) or die('Could not accept incoming connectionn');

        if(socket_getpeername($spawn , $host , $port))
            {
            echo "Client $address : $port is now connected to us. \n";
            }


        $input = socket_read($spawn, 1024) or die('Could not read inputn');


        $input = trim($input);

        $output = strrev($input) . 'n';

        socket_write($spawn, $output, strlen ($output)) or die('Could not write output n');

    }

        socket_close($spawn);
        socket_close($socket);

    ?>
```

Comment: Can you please post what online references you've seen till now? and what is wrong with them?

Comment: [Binary Tides Tutorial](http://www.binarytides.com/php-socket-programming-tutorial/) is one of the online reference I looked. The while loop doesn't work the way I intended to. It takes first string and displays the reverse but then doesn't accept the string further and reverse it.  Even echo "Client $address : $port is now connected to us. \n"; is echod only once.